# Occasional error o.k.k.s.common.zk.ControlNodeTracker - Unknown Error on KAA server

Tags: sdk, apache-zookeeper, kaa

To give you the background, we are running kaa server on ubuntu in combination with MongoDB and have Endpoints attached to it (max 10). Apparently I am seeing following error way too frequently on our server and this makes our Kaa client (C client) throw a segment fault error.

The work around we have found out is restarting kaa-node service on server.
We are planning to go live with product with IoT enabled features and we are worried about this.

Can someone throw light as to what might be going wrong?

I understand the problem is with zookeeper and looks like it does not find operations servers

```
2017-05-11 12:31:23,808 [EPS-core-dispatcher-208419] DEBUG o.k.k.s.o.s.a.a.core.TenantActor - [f8d64123-6861-446f-b937-1e1d398159c8] Processing status request
2017-05-11 12:31:23,808 [EPS-core-dispatcher-208419] TRACE o.k.k.s.o.s.a.a.c.ApplicationActor - [26309946599256320307] Received: org.kaaproject.kaa.server.operations.service.akka.messages.core.stats.StatusRequestMessage@fb460fe
2017-05-11 12:31:23,808 [EPS-core-dispatcher-208419] DEBUG o.k.k.s.o.s.a.a.c.ApplicationActor - [f8d64123-6861-446f-b937-1e1d398159c8] Processing status request
2017-05-11 12:31:23,808 [EPS-core-dispatcher-208419] TRACE o.k.k.s.o.s.a.a.core.TenantActor - [1] Received: org.kaaproject.kaa.server.operations.service.akka.messages.core.stats.ApplicationActorStatusResponse@4ab6ff6c
2017-05-11 12:31:23,808 [EPS-core-dispatcher-208419] DEBUG o.k.k.s.o.s.a.a.c.OperationsServerActor - Received: org.kaaproject.kaa.server.operations.service.akka.messages.core.stats.TenantActorStatusResponse@2fc38dcf
2017-05-11 12:31:23,813 [pool-5-thread-1] ERROR o.k.k.s.common.zk.ControlNodeTracker - Unknown Error
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /operationsServerNodes/operationsServerNodes0000000021
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:111) ~[zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6-1569965]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51) ~[zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6-1569965]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.setData(ZooKeeper.java:1270) ~[zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6-1569965]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.SetDataBuilderImpl$4.call(SetDataBuilderImpl.java:274) ~[curator-framework-2.9.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.SetDataBuilderImpl$4.call(SetDataBuilderImpl.java:270) ~[curator-framework-2.9.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:107) ~[curator-client-2.9.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.SetDataBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(SetDataBuilderImpl.java:267) ~[curator-framework-2.9.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.SetDataBuilderImpl.forPath(SetDataBuilderImpl.java:253) ~[curator-framework-2.9.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.SetDataBuilderImpl.forPath(SetDataBuilderImpl.java:41) ~[curator-framework-2.9.0.jar:na]
        at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.common.zk.operations.OperationsNode$1.doWithZkClient(OperationsNode.java:78) ~[zk-0.10.0.jar:na]
        at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.common.zk.ControlNodeTracker.doZkClientAction(ControlNodeTracker.java:294) [zk-0.10.0.jar:na]
        at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.common.zk.ControlNodeTracker.doZkClientAction(ControlNodeTracker.java:280) [zk-0.10.0.jar:na]
        at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.common.zk.operations.OperationsNode.updateNodeData(OperationsNode.java:75) [zk-0.10.0.jar:na]
        at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.operations.service.loadbalance.DefaultLoadBalancingService.onStatusUpdate(DefaultLoadBalancingService.java:98) [kaa-node-0.10.0.jar:na]
        at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.operations.service.loadbalance.DefaultLoadBalancingService$1$1.run(DefaultLoadBalancingService.java:72) [kaa-node-0.10.0.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

Below is the frequency of this particular error(filename: no of occurrences of error)

```
kaa-node-2017-05-10.0.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-10.1.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-10.2.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-10.3.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-10.4.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-10.5.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-10.6.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-10.7.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-11.0.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-11.1.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-11.2.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-11.3.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-11.4.log:520
kaa-node-2017-05-11.5.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-11.6.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-11.7.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-11.8.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-12.0.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-12.1.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-12.2.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-12.3.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-12.4.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-12.5.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-12.6.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-13.0.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-13.1.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-13.2.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-13.3.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-13.4.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-13.5.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-13.6.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-13.7.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-14.0.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-14.1.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-14.2.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-14.3.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-14.4.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-14.5.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-14.6.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-14.7.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-14.8.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-14.9.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-15.0.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-15.1.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-15.2.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-15.3.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-15.4.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-15.5.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-15.6.log:276
kaa-node-2017-05-15.7.log:875
kaa-node-2017-05-15.8.log:873
kaa-node-2017-05-15.9.log:539
kaa-node-2017-05-16.0.log:879
kaa-node-2017-05-16.1.log:878
kaa-node-2017-05-16.2.log:878
kaa-node-2017-05-16.3.log:878
kaa-node-2017-05-16.4.log:879
kaa-node-2017-05-16.5.log:880
kaa-node-2017-05-16.6.log:877
kaa-node-2017-05-16.7.log:878
kaa-node-2017-05-16.8.log:878
kaa-node-2017-05-16.9.log:735
kaa-node-2017-05-17.0.log:877
kaa-node-2017-05-17.1.log:878
kaa-node-2017-05-17.2.log:878
kaa-node-2017-05-17.3.log:878
kaa-node-2017-05-17.4.log:877
kaa-node-2017-05-17.5.log:876
kaa-node-2017-05-17.6.log:871
kaa-node-2017-05-17.7.log:868
kaa-node-2017-05-17.8.log:877
kaa-node-2017-05-17.9.log:760
kaa-node-2017-05-18.0.log:876
kaa-node-2017-05-18.1.log:876
kaa-node-2017-05-18.2.log:876
kaa-node-2017-05-18.3.log:876
kaa-node-2017-05-18.4.log:877
kaa-node-2017-05-18.5.log:880
kaa-node-2017-05-18.6.log:879
kaa-node-2017-05-18.7.log:878
kaa-node-2017-05-18.8.log:876
kaa-node-2017-05-18.9.log:746
kaa-node-2017-05-19.0.log:876
kaa-node-2017-05-19.1.log:877
kaa-node-2017-05-19.2.log:877
kaa-node-2017-05-19.3.log:879
kaa-node-2017-05-19.4.log:878
kaa-node-2017-05-19.5.log:879
kaa-node-2017-05-19.6.log:1037
kaa-node-2017-05-19.7.log:1285
kaa-node-2017-05-19.8.log:1051
kaa-node-2017-05-20.0.log:1887
kaa-node-2017-05-20.1.log:2400
kaa-node-2017-05-20.2.log:2396
kaa-node-2017-05-20.3.log:1957
kaa-node-2017-05-21.0.log:8640
kaa-node-2017-05-22.0.log:5326
kaa-node-2017-05-22.1.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-22.2.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-22.3.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-22.4.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-23.0.log:0
kaa-node-2017-05-23.1.log:0
```

Comment: Note well: 'urgent' just makes users downvote and move on.  Nobody here cares about your priorities:(

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I had posted it on google group just to realise that it needs to be posted on StackOverflow. Did not mean to demand in any way. I should have been careful!